# Issues reconnecting to Bluetooth headphones in Fedora VM on Qubes OS

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio, bluez, qubes

I have tried various ways to reconnect to my Bluetooth headphones in my Fedora VM after restarting my computer, but they all seem to either take a long time, or not work reliably. I have tried restarting pulseaudio, turning the Bluetooth adaptor off and on again, and turning the headphones off and on again.

It's worth noting that I am also pairing the same Bluetooth headphones with my Android phone.

I then tried suspending the PC instead of shutting it down, but unfortunately after resume all of the USB devices, including the internal Bluetooth adaptor, are disconnected from the VM by Qubes OS, so then I face the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Suspend the PC
2. Wake it up again (which is usually done by pressing the power button), when ready
3. Reconnect the Bluetooth adaptor to the VM
4. Do not skip this step! Put the Bluetooth headphones into **pairing mode**
5. In a terminal in the VM, type systemsettings5
6. Go to the Bluetooth devices page
7. Click on the Bluetooth headphones
8. Click Connect

Comment: A related point: I find that the headphones sometimes disconnect if they are not used for a while. But not to worry - they will auto-reconnect as soon as you start playing audio again - so no action is needed for that case.